# How to use ses dedicated ips, if auto warm up is disabled?

Tags: amazon-cognito, amazon-ses, aws-userpools

I am using a dedicated ip for my ses region. But for some reasons I am not receiving mails from that dedicated ip.

I have disabled the auto warm up process for my dedicated ip pool. As far as my understanding all the mails should go from the dedicated ip. But its not happening.

I am using amazon cognito user pool for user management and expecting to receive inviation and forgot password email from the dedicated ip we have.

Answer (score 0):

Recently aws-congnito has added an option to use developer ses apart from what congito user pool uses internally. As of now, one can use that option only from user pool dasboard, from messgae customization part.